# How do I adjust column width field html in elementor form

Tags: html, css, elementor

I did create an input HTML field and tried to adjust the column width to 100% through Elementor form to be responsive but it does not work. Any advice, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpaUY.jpg)

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>HTML Select Country Phone Code List with Flags</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" required>

        <script>
            var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
            window.intlTelInput(input, {
                separateDialCode: true,
                excludeCountries: ["il"],
                preferredCountries: ["tr"]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add the code you writed (css), please so I can understand more

Comment: Elementor form seems to be a wordpress plugin?
I would assume, you have to give the input (?) and its wrapper a 100% width, but we need the code/more details.

Comment: Yes, it is a plugin and I did insert the HTML code. You can check it, please.

Comment: Please share your CSS code too

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for your solution. You can customize with Elementor as you wish. This plugin is very easy to use
**This plugin:**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/metform/

Comment: How can I use  PHONE NUMBER PREFIX with this plugin?

Comment: https://wpmet.com/doc/form-widgets/

If you follow the documentation, hopefully, you will benefit. But will you reassure me ...! Have you found your solution?

Comment: It does not work at all :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg1QIouKO_Q&list=PL3t2OjZ6gY8NoB_48DwWKUDRtBEuBOxSc